# HorizontalListView inside of ListView

Tags: android, android-listview

I'm trying to add a HorizontalListView (http://www.dev-smart.com/archives/34) to a ListView. The ListView uses an adapter to dynamically attach new HorizontalListView rows for continuous vertical scrolling.

It almost works: the problem is that when the HorizontalListView is scrolled, the ListView will automatically scroll up or down and place the HorizontalListView at the top or bottom edge of the viewport, depending on which it's closest to. How do I stop the HorizontalListView row from snapping into place on scroll?

I used the HorizontalListView as a reference for my "VerticalScrollView":

```
public class VerticalScrollView extends ListView {

public static interface ScrollListener {
    void onScrollEnd();
}

public VerticalScrollView(Context context) {
    super(context);
    initView();
}

public VerticalScrollView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    initView();
}

private synchronized void initView() {
    mTopViewIndex = -1;
    mBottomViewIndex = 0;
    mDisplayOffset = 0;
    mCurrentY = 0;
    mNextY = 0;
    mMaxY = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
    mScroller = new Scroller(getContext());
    setFadingEdgeLength(0);
    setItemsCanFocus(false);
}

@Override
public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {
    switch (ev.getAction()) {
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
        mXDistance = mYDistance = 0f;
        mLastX = ev.getX();
        mLastY = ev.getY();
        break;
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
        final float curX = ev.getX();
        final float curY = ev.getY();
        mXDistance += Math.abs(curX - mLastX);
        mYDistance += Math.abs(curY - mLastY);
        mLastX = curX;
        mLastY = curY;
        if(mXDistance > mYDistance) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return super.onInterceptTouchEvent(ev);
}

@Override
public ListAdapter getAdapter() {
    return mAdapter;
}

@Override
public View getSelectedView() {
    //TODO: implement
    return null;
}

@Override
public void setAdapter(ListAdapter adapter) {
    if(mAdapter != null) {
        mAdapter.unregisterDataSetObserver(mDataObserver);
    }
    mAdapter = adapter;
    mAdapter.registerDataSetObserver(mDataObserver);
    reset();
    super.setAdapter(adapter);
}

private synchronized void reset(){
    initView();
    removeAllViewsInLayout();
    requestLayout();
}

@Override
public void setSelection(int position) {
    //TODO: implement
}

private void addAndMeasureChild(final View child, int viewPos) {
    android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams params = child.getLayoutParams();
    if(params == null) {
        params = new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
    }

    addViewInLayout(child, viewPos, params, true);
    child.measure(MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(getWidth(), MeasureSpec.AT_MOST),
            MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(getHeight(), MeasureSpec.AT_MOST));
}

@Override
protected synchronized void onLayout(
        boolean changed,
        int left,
        int top,
        int right,
        int bottom) {
    super.onLayout(changed, left, top, right, bottom);

    if(mAdapter == null){
        return;
    }

    if(mDataChanged){
        int oldCurrentY = mCurrentY;
        initView();
        removeAllViewsInLayout();
        mNextY = oldCurrentY;
        mDataChanged = false;
    }

    if(mScroller.computeScrollOffset()){
        int scrollY = mScroller.getCurrY();
        mNextY = scrollY;
    }

    if(mNextY <= 0){
        mNextY = 0;
        mScroller.forceFinished(true);
    }
    if(mNextY >= mMaxY) {
        mNextY = mMaxY;
        mScroller.forceFinished(true);
    }

    int dy = mCurrentY - mNextY;

    removeNonVisibleItems(dy);
    fillList(dy);
    positionItems(dy);

    mCurrentY = mNextY;

    if(!mScroller.isFinished()){
        post(mRequestLayoutRunnable);
    }
}

private void fillList(final int dy) {
    int edge = 0;
    View child = getChildAt(getChildCount()-1);
    if(child != null) {
        edge = child.getBottom();
    }
    fillListBottom(edge, dy);

    edge = 0;
    child = getChildAt(0);
    if(child != null) {
        edge = child.getTop();
    }
    fillListTop(edge, dy);
}

private void fillListBottom(int bottomEdge, final int dy) {
    while(bottomEdge + dy < getHeight() && mBottomViewIndex < mAdapter.getCount()) {

        View child = mAdapter.getView(mBottomViewIndex, mRemovedViewQueue.poll(), this);
        addAndMeasureChild(child, -1);
        bottomEdge += child.getMeasuredHeight();

        if(mBottomViewIndex == mAdapter.getCount()-1) {
            mMaxY = mCurrentY + bottomEdge - getHeight();
        }

        if (mMaxY < 0) {
            mMaxY = 0;
        }
        mBottomViewIndex++;
    }
}

private void fillListTop(int topEdge, final int dy) {
    while(topEdge + dy > 0 && mTopViewIndex >= 0) {
        View child = mAdapter.getView(mTopViewIndex, mRemovedViewQueue.poll(), this);
        addAndMeasureChild(child, 0);
        topEdge -= child.getMeasuredHeight();
        mTopViewIndex--;
        mDisplayOffset -= child.getMeasuredHeight();
    }
}

private void removeNonVisibleItems(final int dy) {
    View child = getChildAt(0);
    while(child != null && child.getBottom() + dy <= 0) {
        mDisplayOffset += child.getMeasuredHeight();
        mRemovedViewQueue.offer(child);
        removeViewInLayout(child);
        mTopViewIndex++;
        child = getChildAt(0);

    }

    child = getChildAt(getChildCount()-1);
    while(child != null && child.getLeft() + dy >= getHeight()) {
        mRemovedViewQueue.offer(child);
        removeViewInLayout(child);
        mBottomViewIndex--;
        child = getChildAt(getChildCount()-1);
    }
}

private void positionItems(final int dy) {
    if(getChildCount() > 0){
        mDisplayOffset += dy;
        int top = mDisplayOffset;
        for(int i=0;i<getChildCount();i++){
            View child = getChildAt(i);
            int childHeight = child.getMeasuredHeight();
            child.layout(0, top, child.getMeasuredWidth(), top + childHeight);
            top += childHeight + child.getPaddingBottom();
        }
    }
}

public synchronized void scrollTo(int y) {
    mScroller.startScroll(0, mNextY, 0, y - mNextY);
    requestLayout();
}

public boolean mAlwaysOverrideTouch = true;
protected ListAdapter mAdapter;
private int mTopViewIndex = -1;
private int mBottomViewIndex = 0;
protected int mCurrentY;
protected int mNextY;
private int mMaxY = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
private int mDisplayOffset = 0;
protected Scroller mScroller;
private Queue<View> mRemovedViewQueue = new LinkedList<View>();
private boolean mDataChanged = false;
private float mXDistance;
private float mYDistance;
private float mLastX;
private float mLastY;

private Runnable mRequestLayoutRunnable = new Runnable(){

    @Override
    public void run() {
        requestLayout();
    }
};

private DataSetObserver mDataObserver = new DataSetObserver() {

    @Override
    public void onChanged() {
        synchronized(VerticalScrollView.this){
            mDataChanged = true;
        }
        invalidate();
        requestLayout();
    }

    @Override
    public void onInvalidated() {
        reset();
        invalidate();
        requestLayout();
    }
};
```

EDIT: I can get this to work perfectly by using a plain ListView instead of my custom VerticalScrollView. I'm going to be populating the ListView from the network as the user scrolls down. How can I manage the list item views so that I don't run out of memory?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to get the behavior that I wanted by attaching the HorizontalListViews to a ListView.  I then wrapped my adapter that creates the HorizontalListViews with an EndlessAdapter for continuous scrolling:

https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-endless

I made sure to recycle views in my adapter's getView method to address memory issues. Though, I can still run out of memory if my model layer takes up too much space on the heap.

Does anyone know of a good framework for culling model objects when they go off screen, and reloading them when they need to be displayed again?